# Append a number in the end of a variable name in java

Tags: java, variables, append, variable-names

Suppose that I have a lot of variables defined in my code with names such as this

```
public javax.swing.JPanel BenderPanel1;
public javax.swing.JPanel BenderPanel2;
public javax.swing.JPanel BenderPanel3;
etc...
```

So their general type is like this: `BenderPanel"NUMBER"`.

I want to access some of them and set their visibility with `.setVisible(false);` but the number of those panels which I want to access is user-defined on run time.

Is there any possible way through a library to append a number to the end of each variable in order to access it in a `for` loop, like this:

```
for (int i=1; i<=UserInput; i++)
{
     BenderPanel"i".setVisible(false); // Watch this "i" right there.
}
```

**WITHOUT** the need to add them on `ArrayList` first and do it with the obvious way?

Comment: use array instead of doing this way,array is what you need

Comment: (And don't use public variables, either...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't *create* members dynamically in Java (you *can* access them dynamically via reflection, but there's no need for it here).

Rather than having

```
public javax.swing.JPanel BenderPanel1;
public javax.swing.JPanel BenderPanel2;
public javax.swing.JPanel BenderPanel3;
```

have

```
public javax.swing.JPanel[] BenderPanels;
```

or

```
public List<javax.swing.JPanel> BenderPanels;
```

Then you can loop through them with an enhanced `for` loop.

```
for (javax.swing.JPanel panel : BenderPanels) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Why he can't do this in Java if he can with Reflection?

Comment: @emka86: You can't dynamically create new variables with reflection. You *can* access the existing data members of an object instance using reflection, though, that's true.

Comment: yes, that true but your previous answer before edit just say that he "can't do that in Java"

Answer (score 2):

If you really do not want to store your objects in a data structure like e.g. an ArrayList, I would recommend to use the [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

Especially interesting for you should be the [fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldTypes.html).

Btw: According to the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), variable names shouldn't start with capital letters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also thank you for reminding me JavaNamingConventions which I use almost everywhere but GUI design :D

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide you an idea about using `Reflection`:

```
public class YourClassContainer extends ... {

public javax.swing.JPanel BenderPanel1;
public javax.swing.JPanel BenderPanel2;
public javax.swing.JPanel BenderPanel3;
....
public javax.swing.JPanel BenderPanelXXX;

....

//to access all of them:

for (Field field : YourClassContainer.class.getFields()) {
    if (field.getName().startsWith("BenderPanel")) {
        ((javax.swing.JPanel)field.get(YourClassContainer.this)).setVisible(false);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Well this certainly looks uglier and more code than `ArrayList`, so I will just go for the `ArrayList`. +1 for the example though.

Answer (score -1):

Use Reflection in that Way:

```
YourClasss instance; // this instance has those all JPanel fields
Method setVisible = JPanel.class.getMethod("setVisible", new Class[] {Boolean.class});

List<String> numberOfFieldList = getNumbersOfFieldsToSetInvisible(); 

for (String number : numerOfFieldList) {
  Field benderPanelField = YourClass.getField("BenderPanel" + number);
  Object fieldInYourInstance = benderPanelField.get(instance);
  setVisible.invoke(fieldInYourInstance, Boolean.FALSE);
}
```

Maybe it will help.

Answer (score -1):

Simple example using your setup:

```
    List<Integer> visibleItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    JPanel[] myPanels = new JPanel[]{BenderPanel1, BenderPanel2, BenderPanel3};

    for (int i = 0; i < myPanels .length; i++) {
        myPanels[i].setVisible(false);
        if(visibleItems.contains(i) ){
            myPanels[i].setVisible(true);
        } 
    }
```